# How to keep n decimal places in Java

Tags: java, double, decimal, rounding, digits

Hi All it might be a trivial question but as for now I could not find any solution.So asking for your help!

What I am trying to get is a specific encoding table that looks like this:

```
0.000
0.100
0.200
```

I need to keep track of zeroes as I will use them to reconstruct a part of an specific array. Original loop that was creating those numbers is:

```
for(int k=0;k<m_0;k++){
    for(int l=0;l<m_1;l++){
        for(int a=0;a<a1;a++){
            
            Y[x-1]=0.1*k+0.01*l+0.001*a;
            x++;
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Problem! I could not fix zeros after decimal place and rather then getting table described above I am getting following:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
```

As a solution I have tried to use BigDecimal and DecimalFormat but no success. Any suggestions?

**UPD** Few words what I am trying to do. I am encoding specific array to array and back index correspondence. For example `0.100` will be decomposed into `1 and 0 and 0` and used as array index labeling like:

`Array1[Method(1,0,0,Y(i)][Method(1,0,0,Y(i))]=Array2[1][0][0]`

So that I need an output suitable for assigning array index and string will not do the deal.

Comment: The DecimalFormat class seems the way to go as described below.  Could you post what you're trying to do so that we can see why it failed?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I have described in the Update section what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to get later from those .100 array elements like 1,0 and 0. That is why floating zero is crucial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`DecimalFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is the correct place to look.  You just need the correct format.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
System.out.println(df.format(0.1));
```

Output:

```
0.100
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the DecimalFormat class, I would like to propose the following (which I use quite regularly):

Step 1: Create a function that allows me to specify the number of units to keep. Here is a copy of this function.

```
public static String format(Number n) {
        NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        return format.format(n);
    }
```

Step 2: Call the function whenever you have any output to format. Below is a simple example using this function to set the appropriate decimal place length:

```
System.out.println("Based on this, the wind chill index was calculated to be " + format(chill));
```

Note that you could simply change the line:

```
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

to

```
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(n);
```

depending on your desired decimal length.

Answer (score 2):

When you are printing the numbers, you can use this:

```
System.out.format("%.3f", yourDecimalNumber);
```